# discord.py slash commands raise an exception that username cannot contain "discord"

Tags: python, discord.py

When I use slash commands I get an exception that Username cant contain "discord" even though neither the bot nor the user have "discord" in their names

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord import app_commands

load_dotenv()

token = os.getenv('TOKEN')

intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=1128263298152927294))
    print('Command tree synced.')

@tree.command(description="Sends the bot's latency.",name='ping',guild=discord.Object(1128263298152927294))
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.response.send_message("Hello!")

client.run(token)
```

Exception is:

```
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'ping' raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In name: Username cannot contain "discord"
```

Ive tried using different bots/names and different users. Ive also tried using discord.ext.commands.Bot and it also returned the same exception

Comment: Make sure you are not actually naming your bot `Discord` somewhere in the Developer Portal. Also, make sure to uninstall any 3rd party library that maybe interferes here as well.

Comment: Oh my god i didnt realize that the application name actually mattered, i thought it was the bot name only that was important. this fixed it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you named your application `Discord` either as the `username` (/bot) or name of the `application name` (/information) in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Simply renaming one of them will resolve the error! Read more about it [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user)